# Radial quantization and time order

Tags: operators, time, definition, conformal-field-theory, wick-rotation

In CFT, one ususally begins quantization by defining radial ordering on the complex plane, with the notion of radial ordering being the equivalence of time ordering. This is often "motivated" by making a conformal map from the (assuming Euclidena signautre ) cylinder $\mathbf{r}=(t,x)$ to the complex plane via $z\equiv e^{(t+ix)}$. Is the following identiy true?
\begin{equation}
              \langle\mathcal{T}\phi(\mathbf{r}_1)....\phi(\mathbf{r}_n)\rangle=\langle\mathcal{R}\phi'({z}_1)....\phi'({z}_n)\rangle
\end{equation}
where the l.h.s denotes the time ordered products under $\mathcal{T}$ ordering, and $\phi'$ is the tranformed fields under the cylinder to  complex plane map. Does the identiy hold for non-primary fields too?

Comment: Where are the Jacobian factors in the transformation rule? Are you assuming vanishing conformal dimension of the operators?

Comment: @Qmechanic they are in the ‘ notation.

Comment: How does the prime notation deal with non-primary fields??

Comment: The primed fields are simply the tranformed fields after the plane to cylinder mapping. I dont see how whether they tranform nicely as primary fields matter. Foe me the only difference would be, for the primaries, the prime ' means a Jacobian factor.